# Want vertical dash line in equation?

Tags: equations

I Want vertical dashed line in equation without using of package `\usepackage{arydshln}`.

Comment: which equation?

Comment: How long should this line be? Should it span the whole length of the equation in case the equation spans several lines? Should it be placed to the left, to the right, flushed to one of the margins? Please describe clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please be more specific. In the present formulation a formal solution is even `\begin{equation} \text{vertical dashed line} \end{equation}`. ;-)

Comment: Interestingly, I found no vertical dashed lines in the comprehensive symbol list.  There was an interesting wavy vertical line, a lot of dashed arrows and a lot of symbols with dash in the name but no actual dashes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\usepackage{textcomp}

\textbrokenbar
```